# Confusion Surrounding "Marginal Models"

Tags: regression, terminology, marginal-model

I was reading the following paper ([https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~jiashun/Research/Area/Marginal.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ejiashun/Research/Area/Marginal.pdf)) where **Marginal Regression Models** have been defined as follows:

[image]

However, I was always under the impression in which Marginal Regression Models were synonymous with Hierarchical Regression Models (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_model):

[image]

Although the Wikipedia page shows a simple linear regression with a single explanatory variable - I always thought that marginal regression models are used to model the relationship between a response variable and many explanatory variables for different "cohorts". For example, the effect of height, weight and age on salary - for different genders and different education levels (e.g. male university graduates, female university graduates, males without university degrees, females without university degrees).

**My Question:** Are marginal regression models only supposed to be used to study the relationship between a single explanatory variable and the response variable? Why would someone **only** want to regress individual combinations of covariates and dependent variables? Shouldn't there be an option to regress many explanatory variables?